# OpenCV eye tracking on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm looking to do basic eye tracking in android using the OpenCV api. I've found that there seem to be two ways to use opencv in Andriod, either by using their c++ wrapper or by using JavaCV api. I'm willing to do either but I'm looking for some idea or sample code as to how i would track basic eye movement with either platform. I'm leaning toward the JavaCV api because it looks easier to use but I could really use some sort of tutorial on the basics of using it with android.

Comment: Quick question: Are you going to use the camera as input source or are you going to use videos?

Comment: I would be using the camera as the input source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you already looked into JNI (Java Native interface), JavaCV is exactly the same thing as OpenCV. As per eye tracking, you will need to get the live video feed from the camera and locate the participant's eyes in the frames using template matching and blink detection. 
You will just have to make your View implements [Camera.PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) in order to get a hold on the camera feed.

The [OpenCV Site on eye tracking](http://opencv-code.com/Real_Time_Eye_Tracking_and_Blink_Detection) provides some sample codes that will help you track the eyes.

If you want to see an example of opencv on android, click on [this open source code](http://javacv.googlecode.com/files/facepreview-src-20101202.zip).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much those are really helpful. One question, probably stupid but, the OpenCV Site has great examples for exactly what I'm looking to do, but how would I incorporate that code into my java based android app? Would I just use the methods I see and re-write in java or what? I'm kinda of new so I'm just wondering what the best way to use those sample codes would be?

Comment: well the code on the opencv site is a .c program; you will just use JNI to either use it directly in android or use javacv precompiled for android (quite frankly, I would go with the latter). Personally, I have not done opencv on android, so I can't really tell you much about it. I'm sure you've installed opencv/javacv for android already, if not here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list

Comment: I know this is an old question but I just want to point out that the link to the OpenCV example seems to be obsolete.