# android - eye detection even without face detection during camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, preview, eye-detection

is there any library for detecting an eye in a given rectangle (and the eye's size) , while the camera preview is still showing its content (non stop) ?

i need to find an easy way to acheive this . i've found out that there is an API for face detection , and that on android 4 they also added eyes detection , but only if it found a face , yet i need to find an eye even without any face.

Comment: can you please explain? is this a joke?

Comment: Of course. No confusion intended.

Answer (score 3):

You could always ook at the [source code for Android](https://plus.google.com/100301252568537087423/posts/3NngLGAjVgG) and see how they do Eye detection.

Otherwise check out this question: [OpenCV eye tracking on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959423/opencv-eye-tracking-on-android)

If you want to see an example of opencv on android, [click on this open source code](http://javacv.googlecode.com/files/facepreview-src-20101202.zip).

Comment: since i have a very little experience of C under android , i have to ask : is there an API for that ? maybe a quick shortcut that doesn't involve low level coding on my behalf ? if so , is there a sample code for this? according to what i see on the links , they are talking about finding the whole face . not sure if they allow just the eyes .

Answer (score 1):

opencv is best lib for working with face and eye Detection Using opencv you can do:
 http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/
Example Code:
http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/